# Javascript Shift+Enter (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, keycode

Had a look and found some things on this, but nothing seems to work as I'd like it.

Initially I had my solution working with internet explorer and chrome, but not firefox (which is unsatisfactory for me to not have working)

What I'm looking for is a simple text area, which sends data on enter key, but creates a new line on Shift+Enter. The following is what I have

```
function goReturn(e,str) {

  var e = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if (e.shiftKey && e=="13") {
    document.getElementById("wall").value = 
        document.getElementById("wall").value+"\n";
  } else if(e=="13"){
    // ...continue to send data
  }
}
```

This sends the data on enter, but also sends the data on shift and enter (which is the problem I have).

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Why are you enclosing your numbers in quotes? `e.which` is not a string!

Comment: Please don't change the default, expected behaviour of text areas. Pressing return should always insert a new line. If anything, you should leave that much of the default behaviour intact and use shift+enter to submit the form instead.

Comment: You're shadowing `e` on the first line in the function. `e.shiftKey` will always be false (unless you added that property to String prototypes...). I'm assuming your actual code doesn't do this, can you update your question with it?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the submit call in your form (onsubmit="..."). There, check if the last `enter` was in combination with `shift`. If yes, return false to the submit request.

You can also try if returning `false` on `e.shiftKey && e=="13"` is sufficient.

Comment: Hi the textarea itself doesn't come from within a form, it sits on it's own. And calls the function onkeyup (and one onkeydown)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cancel the event propagation through `e.cancel = true;` but I see that currently you're overwriting the `e` variable (event object). If you would change your code to the following, you should be fine:

```
function goReturn(e_obj,str) {

  var e = (window.Event) ? e_obj.which : e_obj.keyCode;
  if (e.shiftKey && e=="13") {
    document.getElementById("wall").value = 
        document.getElementById("wall").value+"\n";
    e_obj.cancel = true;
  } else if(e=="13"){
    // ...continue to send data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a jQuery plugin for my own use case and it might fit yours: http://cburgmer.github.com/jquery-shiftenter/

The plugin takes care of handling the return key and also displays a hint on focus to explain the behaviour.